# async method not returning when called from TestMethod

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, asynchronous

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and MSTest for unit testing my async method. I have async method as below:

```
    public async Task<Client> AddClientAsync(Client newClient)
    {
        newClient.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
        base.Insert(newClient);
        await unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
        return newClient;
    }
```

UnitOfWorkAsync SaveChangesAsync() method:

```
    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Data Context SaveChangesAsync() method:

```
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return await this.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        SyncObjectsStatePreCommit();
        var changesAsync = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        SyncObjectsStatePostCommit();
        return changesAsync;
    }
```

I have written following unit test method to test it.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task AddClientAsync_Success()
    {
        Client client = new Client()
        {
            Id=2,
            FirstName="John",
            LastName="Tylor",
            MaritalStatusId=1,
            RecordStatus=1                
        };

        var result = await clientAppService.AddClientAsync(client);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

When I run/debug test case control reaches till below line and never returns. Its kind of getting stuck and keeps waiting endlessly at this line and test never completes.

```
await unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Update: It executes SaveChangesAsync() method which also returns result but post that test never completes.

Comment: Can you show us `SaveChangesAsync`? Since it returns a `Task`, it's perfectly possible for that method to *return*, and yet the returned Task might never be completed.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior : Added code.

Comment: Is there any locking code in the `SyncObjectsState*()` methods?  This is the first place I would look.  Tasks don't have any guarantee to be in the same thread or the thread order that calls are made.

Comment: Another thought: you can take advantage of the `IDisposable` interface to make sure the `SyncObjectStatePostCommit()` gets called after `SyncObjectStatePreCommit()` in the case of an exception being thrown.  You simply call one in the constructor and the other in the `Dispose()` method, and put your object in a `using` statement.  At least use a `try`/`finally` statement to ensure the post commit method is executed.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch : There is no lock used in both commit methods.

Comment: Try adding ConfigureAwait(false) on the await tasks, this makes sure that the any of the available thread can be used for continuation tasks instead of the Asp.net worker tread. More info at http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with [this deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html), but can't tell from the posted code. Please reduce to a [minimal, reproducible error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy/paste into VS and see the deadlock.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Tried ConfigureAwait(false) but that didn't help.

Comment: @PankajKapare: That has nothing to do with my comment. It's a totally different blog post than the one posted by Sri.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Sorry it was for Sri but accidently typed your name.

Comment: @PankajKapare: No worries.